# Android TextSwitcher: how to make every text stay?

Tags: android

In my app I have following code:

```
    tw.setText("1");
    tw.setText("2");
```

I thought it will let 1 stay for a while and then display 2, but in fact, It only display 2, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is this an example of `TextSwitcher` or `TextView`?  Your code doesn't really show anything other than you overwriting a `TextView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to replace `TextView` text. Then try this way

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tw.setText("2");
                }
            }, 4000);
```

Comment: This will be along the line of what the OP needs.